# Bulk DNS with LetsEncrypt

Tags: dns, cloudflare, nameservers, netlify

I have built an app in that allows users to create listings; that also allows them to purchase a domain to singularly target that listing for marketing purposes.

When a domain is purchased, my current workflow is the following:

1. Update nameservers at registrar to point to CloudFlare.
2. Setup new site in CloudFlare to point to the singular app IP address, and also force SSL to proxy the request through (and a handful of optimization settings and page rules).
3. Set database flag in listing to `true` so that when the index page loads, it loads their listing instead of my marketing index page.

Some things I hate about this setup:

1. Setting up a CloudFlare site is cumbersome (especially copying over any optimization settings).
2. DNS settings within each site are all the same, but the thought of ever changing my site IP or CloudFlare settings sounds like a pain in the butt to update each one individually.

Currently, the app is hosted on DigitalOcean, but I'd like to move things over to Netlify and use their Lambda service. I'd also love to use their domain alias service since it provides access to SSLs through LetsEncrypt which would DRAMATICALLY simplify things, but they cap the limit at 100; which just isn't going to work at scale.

My ideal setup would be:

1. JAM-stack service at Netlify.
2. Ability to manage domain DNS in bulk instead of a "per-site" basis since they always point to the same site "base".
3. LetsEncrypt management that doesn't flake out past a certain number of sites.
4. The "out-of-the-box" benefits that Netlify and CloudFlare DNS services provide (automatic CDN-management, www redirects, etc)

I'm a bit inexperienced with DNS, so I'm unsure if my current workflow is way over-the-top, or if my ideal workflow is a pipe-dream. Any nudges in the right direction would be a huge help. Thank you very much!

Comment: The 100 applies to the number of SANs inside a certificate. You can create one certificate per name, and you do not have limits then.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks for the response! You don't happen to know how Netlify deals with certificate generation from domain aliases, do you? I may have been given wrong information when I reached out to their support.

Comment: I don't and the problem is that it is as is not a lot ontopic here as not really a programming problem. As for Let's Encrypt limits you can find them all here: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/ the only case where 100 appears is in "If you have a lot of subdomains, you may want to combine them into a single certificate, up to a limit of 100 Names per Certificate. " which says nothing about the number of separate certificates you can have (no real limits in fact, just some rate limits)